# Set precision using decimalFormat error - Java

Tags: java, format, double, rounding

I am attempting to use the DecimalFormat java class for the first time, and I am running into a strange issue. I would like 125.295 to round to 125.30. I would think the format should automatically include the 0, but maybe I'm incorrect.

```
double num = 125.295;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
String str = df.format(num);
System.out.println(str); //this is yielding 125.3 instead of 125.30
```

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: use `new DecimalFormat("#.00")`

Answer (score 3):

The DecimalFormat class treats '#' as "hide trailing zeroes" or '0' as "show the zeroes". As per the API for DecimalFormat:

```
0   Number  Yes Digit
#   Number  Yes Digit, zero shows as absent
```

So you should use DecimalFormat("#.00") instead of DecimalFormat("#.##") if you want it to show trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DecimalFormat` like this:

```
   double num = 125.295;
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.00");
   System.out.println("sum (DecimalFormat) : " + df.format(num));
```

Output:

```
   125.30
```

Comment: Specifying more `#` before the decimal point doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Andreas now more effecient

Comment: Output of second example is `125.3`, which is exactly what OP doesn't want.

Comment: @Andreas ok andres removing the second possibility